# Delete Key on Macbook AIr

Tags: nautilus, keyboard, shortcut-keys, macbook

I have ubuntu 14.10 installed on my macbook air 2013 (6,2) and I want to know if it's possible for me to change the behavior of the 'delete' key to that of the backspace key as there is no backspace button on this keyboard. in the sense that when i'm navigating files on the desktop or in nautilus that hitting the 'delete' key alone deletes the currently highlighted file, which is the normal ubuntu behavior of the backspace key. If anyone has a solution for this problem please let me know. thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a 'backspace' on your Macbook air. Simply press Fn+ Delete to get a Backspace. It should be the same no matter what OS you are using. Hope it helps.

Comment: right, but I don't want to have to use more than the 'delete' button. I want to just press delete.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Check this: http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/09/15/faq-how-to-disableremap-a-keyboard-key-in-linux

Comment: @PakLongWu: don't just send people off onto a link...  take the relevant information from the link, [edit] your answer and provide it as a second option.

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you can redefine the Delete-key on MacBook to work as delete rather than backspace. Or any other key.

### Approach 1: using xmodmap

Create or edit the file ~/.Xmodmap

Add the following entry to it:

```
keycode 22 = Delete
```

Test it with

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

To make ir permanent, make sure it runs every time when you log in: add to Startup Applications, e.g. from the Dash.
If you want to modify other keys but do not know their codes, you can run the event monitoring program `xev` and try the keys.

### Approach 2: modifying xkb mapping

As alternative you can modify the /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc file with the relevant key mappings, but then you need sudo access.

```
key <BKSP> {   [ Delete, Delete  ]   };
```

You may need to clear the compiled keyboard mappings cache for this to take effect on next reboot:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*
```

And restart.